# NixOS: Mediatek 7961 wifi not working properly (Vivobook Pro 16x)

Tags: wifi, nixos

I have a Vivobook Pro 16x which has a `mediatek 7961` wifi chip and I just installed Nixos on it. Everything works except the Wifi. The wifi works occasionally, but not always.

I updated the kernel to the latest version by setting `boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_latest;`, as I read that was needed for the `mediatek 7961` chip to work.

I’ve also tried setting `networking.networkmanager.wifi.backend = "iwd"`, which seems to work slightly better, but only for a few seconds.

So my wifi works for a bit, few seconds, and then nothing loads.

Are there any other settings I can try out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I was unable to fix it through software. Luckily it was easy to replace the wifi chip. So I did that, now using an AX200 chip, which works flawlessly with the default settings in NixOS.